# Autofac with Moq constructor 'Castle.Proxies.ClassXProxy' not found

Tags: c#, moq, autofac

I am using Autofac along with Moq to facilitate the unit test.
I have the following mocking code, but no luck

```
MockObject.Setup(factory => factory.Request(this.testSubsystemName, RestSharp.Method.GET).BuildServiceConnector(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), null).Execute<ConfigurationEntries>())
                  .Returns(new RestResponse<ConfigurationEntries> { Content = this.subSystemConfigs.ToEntries().ToString(), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });
```

inside the factory class, the request method returns a ClassX object.

```
    public virtual ClassX Request(string resource, RestSharp.Method method)
    {
        return new ClassX(resource, method);
    }
```

When I run the code, it gives me exception as:

> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.ClassXProxy' not found.

I have tried the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682027/can-i-access-the-full-power-of-autofac-in-unittests-using-the-moq-integration) to register the ClassX on componentRegistry

```
mockScope.Container.ComponentRegistry.Register(RegistrationBuilder.ForType<ClassX>()
                                     .As<ClassX>()
                                     .CreateRegistration<ClassX, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>());
```

Can someone give me some direction how to fix this properly. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, in order to mock an object, Moq needs a `protected` parameterless constructor.

Comment: You should probably post the full stack trace on the exception as well as ClassX, but this definitely looks like a Moq/DynamicProxy issue, not Autofac. Try doing a simpler test removing Autofac from the mix to verify and you may be able to simplify your question to get better answers.

Comment: I worked round this issue by creating mock object of dependency line by line.
I think the issue is that there is no parameterless constructor for ClassX, After I mock the request method to return a mock ClassX with string and method, then everything works. Thanks for your guys though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this error code and are mocking a client the package might have been updated and requires another parameter. You won't see an inline error for some reason due to local caching.